# OleDbConnection ConnectionString to Resource File

Tags: c#, resources, connection-string, ole

I want to create OLE Connection to a File placed in Project's Resources.
How should I write the Connection String?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's expected that you try to do something for yourself first. Do some research, give it a try and then ask for the specific problems you run into, with a sample code/example.

Comment: Appreciate your help

Comment: As in you are using an oledb file driver for excel/text etc? You will need to write it to disk in order to access it.

Comment: Thank you! I spent some Time looking how to connect to a Resource. Now I know it's impossible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Research and thanks to **Alex K.** I've found out there is no Way to make a Connection String to a Project's Resource.
You should copy the Resource to Build Location and make a Connection String to that File.